# Можно-ли сбросить запрос на сервер?

Tags: ios, swift

Пытаюсь сделать валидацию логина.

Валидация состоит из 3ех частей.

1. Проверка логина на наличие символов
2. Проверка логина через регулярное выражение
3. Отправка данных на сервер и проверка занятости логина.

Может сложиться такая ситуация, что пока ответ придет с сервера пользователь удалит несколько символов и проверка вернет ошибку по пункту 2 (Проверка логина через регулярное выражение)

Можно ли как-то в этот момент отменить запрос на сервер.

Правка (больше деталей)

У логина есть 4 состояния:

1. Пустой
2. Не подходит
3. Свободен
4. Занят

У каждого из 4ех состояний имеется свой строковой параметр
Первые две проверки проходят локально. 
Если они прошли отправляется запрос на сервер.

Блокировать UI не желательно.

Comment: Запретить (дизаблите) пользователю трогать что-либо пока не придет ответ от сервера!

Comment: Запрос отменить нельзя, он уже улетел и даже если вы пошлете в след гонца с депешей, то к тому времени запрос уже может быть обработан. Короче та еще морока, лучше дизаблите, а если ответ от сервера не приходит, то по таймеру инаблите

Comment: Почему первые две проверки делаются на сервере? они должны делаться на клиенте, и только третья на сервере. а вот уже после отправки данных (подтверждения верности ввода) - делаются все три на стороне сервера.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Я так понял, что первые 2 у него делаются на клиенте, что в принципе логично

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Возможно и так, мне показалось иначе, собственно в чем проблема тогда не вижу от слова совсем... с сервера отправляем ответ не просто "верно\неверно" но и сам логин который проверяли, и если на клиенте он уже изменился - отклоняем результат проверки как ненужный\недействительный.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков тоже вариант, хотя пользователь может не понять, что он сделал не так и почему проверка не прошла (изменил данные до подтверждения текущей проверки) и как-то необычно было бы ему сообщать, что-то типа "Ваш логин Вася прошел проверку, но так как вы изменили его на Петя, то увы" ))

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Результат третьей проверки можно вообще не выводить если логин возвращенный сервером не совпадает с текущим логином у клиента. Просто повторно отправлять запрос на проверку нового логина, и ждать его результата(можно имитатор загрузузки вывести рядом с полем - типо проверка еще идет).

Comment: Поправил ответ. Может просто есть метод который не учитывает результат который приходит с сервера.

Comment: @ВикторМишустин а вы блокируйте не UI целиком, а только поле ввода логина

Comment: **Может просто есть метод который не учитывает результат который приходит с сервера** не совсем понятно, что имеется в виду. Вы же сами обрабатываете ответ от сервера, так обрабатывайте так как вам надо.

Comment: Вопрос в том, как результату с сервера понять, был ли этот метод вызван еще раз после отправки данных, и какая проверка там сработала.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отслеживайте ввод и в зависимости от этого обрабатывайте ответ от сервера, а также [отменяйте](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontask/1411591-cancel) предыдущие запросы.

К примеру, введен логин, проходящий проверки -> Отправляется запрос -> вводится еще что-то -> запрос еще не отработал - отменили -> новый запрос -> вводится еще что-то -> запрос уже отработал, но так как входящие данные уже другие - с ответом ничего не делаем -> новый запрос -> ничего не вводилось -> обрабатываем ответ.

Comment: Интересовал только метод отмены. Спасибо за помощь!